# Referencing @Service from delegate class

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I am having trouble using an @Service annotated JAX-RS resource from within a delegate class. Here is my setup:

MyServlet.java

```
package com.company.mobileservice.servlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestHandler;

public class MyServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {

    @Autowired
    MyDelagate delegate;

    private void writeResponse(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String delegateResponse) {
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/json");

            String callback = request.getParameter("callback");
            if (callback != null) {
                delegateResponse = callback + "(" + delegateResponse + ");";
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Callback was null.");
            }

            response.getWriter().write(delegateResponse);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private String delegateGetRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return delegate.handleRequest(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        String delegateResponse = delegateGetRequest(request);
        writeResponse(request, response, delegateResponse);
    }
}
```

MyDelegate.java

```
package com.company.mobileservice.servlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.company.mobileservice.cards.CardResource;

@Component
public class MyDelagate {

    @Autowired
    private CardResource cardResource;

    public String handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return addCard(request);
    }

    // Proxies the request to CardResource
    private String addCard(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String accountID = request.getParameter("accountID");

        Card card = new Card();
        card.setPan(accountInformation.getAccountNumber().toString());
        card.setPaymentTypeId("ABCD1234");
        Response response = cardResource.addCard(request, "TEST", null, card);
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

CardResource.java

```
package com.company.mobileservice.cards;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.company.mobileservice.model.Card;

@Path("/{appId}/cards")
@Service
@Scope("singleton")
public class CardResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Response addCard(
          @Context HttpServletRequest request,
          @PathParam("appId") String appId,
          @QueryParam("location") String location,
          Card card) {

        // Do work here
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is call my @Service from within the delegate. I was able to successfully inject the CardResource in to my delegate from the application context, but I was wondering if there is another way to access this service by using the RESTful @Path method.

Comment: Well, you can write a REST client for that. But why you want to do that?

Comment: I wanted to add, that I am trying to avoid making an external HTTP call to the @Service itself, since I want access to it from within the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching, I've determined that this isn't possible. I was hoping for some kind of service directory that I could to get the appropriate service from. In the end, I decided to just make a call to the service at localhost. It essentially does the job, but it sure would be nice if I could make REST service calls from within my own application without having to configure a client.